# How to run ng lint on specific folders - not by excluding, but by including certain folders?

Tags: angular, tslint

I am trying to run ng lint on specific folders of my project in one go. Say for example, I have the folders F1, F2, F3, F4, F5, F6, F7, F8, F9, F10 under src, and I want to run ng lint only on F1,F3 and F4 - and I want to do it in one go - how can I achieve that.

What I have tried is running the following:

```
ng lint | grep ./src/F1*
```

But the above command is good for one folder - how to run ng lint on multiple folders in one go.

Comment: Just a update: the grep doesnot work either

Comment: in grep remove `./src`

Answer (score 0):

Try running 
`ng lint WorkManager | grep <file_name | folder_name>`

just put the folder or file name, don't put the path.